# Modify JSON files in GCS bucket to change the datatype of a field from String to Array (GCP)

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata, google-cloud-storage

I have a use case where we are receiving millions of JSON files into our GCS bucket. I am creating an external table on top of the GCS bucket. problem is for one particular field the data type is not consistent.

few files have string and other has Array.
My question is

example:

1. can we alter the json to make these strings to Array ? or any other recommendation to handle this

```
**string**:
 "ing": {
    "info": "abc,def",
    "details": []
  },
  
**array**:

"ing": {
    "info": [
      "abc,def",
      "abc,efg"
    ],
    "details": []
  },
```

I tried by adding the [] to string value and queryng the external table it works . But need  a way to efficiently alter the 1M json files to add brackets.
am expecting move this data from external table into biquery table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope below query gives you a hint to handle your problem

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '{"ing": {"enfo": "abc,def", "details": []}}' json UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"ing": {"info": "abc,def", "details": []}}' json UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"ing": {"info": ["abc,def", "abc,efg"], "details": []}}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"ing": {"info": null, "details": []}}'
)
SELECT COALESCE(
          JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(json, '$.ing.info'),
          ARRAY(SELECT e FROM UNNEST([JSON_VALUE(json, '$.ing.info')]) e WHERE e IS NOT NULL)
       ) AS info 
  FROM sample_table;
```

**Query results**

[image]

###### External Table

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `your-project.stackoverflow`;

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE `stackoverflow.sample_table` (
  json STRING
)
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  field_delimiter = CHR(1),
  uris = ['https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CIW3UmvYr2JAmSounOY6l5dUFUJCOJOH']
);

SELECT COALESCE(
          JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(json, '$.ing.info'),
          [JSON_VALUE(json, '$.ing.info')]
       ) AS info 
  FROM `stackoverflow.sample_table`;
```

Comment: :thanks for the response. I have created a external table on top these 2 json. 

SELECT COALESCE(
          JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(ing.info, '$.ing.info'),
          [JSON_VALUE(ing.info, '$.ing.info')]
       ) AS info 
  FROM `project.raw.test` t1;
Facing error:Error while reading table: project.raw.test, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Array specified for non-repeated field: ing.info

Comment: Are you able to show how `ing.info` in your table looks like ?

Comment: Issue is, I have external table created with schema for this field as "Array". This Array schema can not handle "String" type . hence it fails . Is there a way to edit the json ? I tried by adding [] to the string value and it works. if I could some how edit the json in GCS bucket and prefix and append the brackets , it should work.

Comment: are you using *--source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"*  when you create an external table?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: @Vijaya, since the json schema is not consistent in your json file, I think loading a file as json format will fail.   kindly consider to load it as CSV first and apply the query in my answer.  I've updated answer to add sample query for it.

Comment: I have files with Null values as well , this is working fine with not null. But for Null its failing with "Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field"

Comment: @Vijaya, array with *null* can't be written in a table, so you should handle *null* exception if your json data has a *null* value or missing field of `ing.info`.  see my updated answer.

Comment: ,any help on  how to handle a record datatype

Comment: Would you post an another question about a record datatype with a sample data ? I'm not sure how your data looks like..